# When object mapper is serialized and mapped to sub objects, it gives the object with backslashes

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

What should be done in order to produce a json object which is writed in json generator such that it doesnot produce backslashes.In my code,

```
ObjectMapper modifierObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
       SimpleModule modifierModule = new SimpleModule("JSONModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, "com.demo.model", "custom-object-mapper"));
         modifierModule.setSerializerModifier(new demoBeanSerializerModifier());
        modifierObjectMapper.registerModule(modifierModule);
                      field.setValue(modifierObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(args[i]));
```

On giving this code, when multiple sub objects are mapped, it gives twice the number of backslashes. What to do to make it without any slashes